# JComboBox selects the first item by iteself

Tags: java, swing, selection, jcombobox

I have made a combobox which is being filled up with the database entries. The problem that i'm currently facing is that when I write "H" the list gets filled with all the names starting with "H" as required but the first name in the list automatically gets selected. How to avoid this problem?

```
String ch = text.getText();
if (ch.equals("")) {
    combo.setVisible(false);               
} else {                
    try {                  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userlogin", "root","12345");
        Statement st = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT author_name FROM scrpd_authors WHERE author_name LIKE '"+ ch + "%'");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("author_name");
            if (name.equals("")) {
                searchitems.addItem("");
            } else {
                searchitems.addItem(rs.getString("author_name"));
                searchitems.setVisible(true);                            
            }                        
        }
        connect.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
 }
```

Please note the combobox is being filled with all my desired entries based on the mysql query, the problem is just with the selection of the first entry by itself.

Comment: What exactly should be selected then? You may use a listener and then de-select the first entry after the list is populated.

Comment: Make sure the first item is an empty `String`.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Best case the user already has the right option selected, worst case he needs to move down to pick the right one, which he has to do in your approach as well.

Comment: Also, make searchitems visible outside the loop.

Comment: In the listener which I have written to print the selected item on the screen, it prints the first name initially and then the name on which I click.

Comment: In the listener handle a case for items loading into the list.

Comment: @tmwanik I was thinking of this possibility but the database cant contain a null entry

Comment: @user714965 yes, I will close it. Thanks

Comment: @Heuster It's a problem because suppose the name is "H. M. Maurer" as soon as I write H combobox will contain an H and Hasan as the first item so Hasan will immediately be printed on the screen whereas my requirement is H. M. Maurer, which can be selected with a listener but two names will be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the first name in the list automatically gets selected. How to avoid this problem?

Then use:

```
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```

after the data has been loaded.

Or maybe you could use a [Combo Box Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/combo-box-prompt/).

Answer (score 2):

that's a quirk of the not-editable JComboBox when adding to an empty box:

- using `addItem(item)` will select that item
- using `insertItemAt(item, 0)` will not select that item

That quirk is independent on whether the filling happens on the model or on the view-

So if deselecting after filling the model (as suggested by Rob) is not an option, you can use the insert method (either on the view or on the model):

```
// model 
model.addElementAt(item, model.getSizes();
// alternatively view
combo.insertItemAt(item, combo.getItemCount());
```

Generally, it's recommended to do model manipulations on the model  (vs. on the cover methods on the view) - this way you can implement and test your model handling independent of the view.